# What could be the cause of "ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model: 31704179198" in pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I get this error message whenever I try to run code that uses the .dae extension.

I've been getting this error on code for a problem I've been working on. Eventually, I ran code that I found online for a different problem and got the same error. This makes me think that it's some error with how I'm running the solver (ipopt) rather than the code itself

Here's a link to the code from GitHub that I'm getting an error message with: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/dae/Optimal_Control.py

I've been evoking the solve with:
pyomo solve --solver=ipopt filename.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the DAE examples come with a second Python script for running the model. Models formulated with Pyomo.DAE are meant to be run from Python scripts and not using the `pyomo solve` command line. The optimal control problem you're looking at can be solved by using the command

```
python run_Optimal_Control.py
```

If you take a look at this file you'll see the syntax for applying a discretization scheme to the dynamic model, creating a solver object using the `SolverFactory`, solving the model, and plotting the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Hopefully I can finally figure this out now